# Timing first call of setInterval differently than the rest

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to time the first call of `setInterval` differently then the rest, so that it takes 100 seconds before the first call and then 5 seconds between all the rest. This is my code:

```
setTimeout((setInterval(test,5000)),100000);

function test(){
   alert("hi!");
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pppn8qnn/)

Comment: You're currently invoking `setInterval` immediately. You can either wrap it in a function or do something like `setInterval.bind(null, test, 5000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument needs to be a function. You are using `(setInterval(test,5000))`. That is not a function, but a statement that runs immediately so that the JS engine can evaluate the result and pass it to `setTimeout`, in the same way it would immediately evaluate `(3+3)` and pass `6` to the function if you had used `setTimeout((3+3), 100000)` instead.

So the solution is to pass a function:

```
setTimeout(function() { setInterval(test,5000); },100000);

function test(){
   alert("hi!");
}
```

An unrelated tip: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging like this, so you don't have to click away alert boxes all of the time.